# Can you set a role as author?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, permissions

I'm fairly new to WordPress and I'm trying to figure out how to best set up permissions.

I want to restrict groups of people to only edit certain pages (IT department to only edit IT pages, HR department to only edit HR pages and so on).

From what I've read you take away permissions to 'edit others pages' from a role and then set the author of the page to the person you want to edit it.

Is there a standard way to set multiple authors or maybe a way to make a role an author rather than a single user?

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to rephrase the last sentence? A role is something assigned to a user, a user can have a role, whereas your question suggests a role itself can log in, which makes little sense. Editors don't login, users with the editor role log in.

Answer (score 1):

No, to set a users role you have to have the admin role. Authors cannot change or set roles

An important thing to keep in mind is that it isn't an editor who logs in, it's a user with the edit role. Roles don't login, they're just collections of privileges assigned to users.

> Is there a standard way to set multiple authors

Yes, give multiple users the author role or higher, a site can have more than one author

> a way to make a role an author rather than a single user?

A role isn't a thing, it's just a collection of privileges. The equivalent is hiring the concept of a degree in medicine rather than a person who earned that degree and became a doctor. Be careful of how you word things

> I want to restrict groups of people to only edit certain pages (IT department to only edit IT pages, HR department to only edit HR pages and so on).

You've ran into a classic XY problem, where you asked about a problem with your solution, not the original problem. You should ask a new question with just the above paragraph. Be aware that this isn't something you can do clicking around the interface, there will be code involved

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set a role as a post's author in WordPress. In core it is also not possible to assign more than one author to one post.

What you are trying to achieve can probably be done with plugins which allow creation of user groups along with assigning access control rights to these groups. I guess there are several such plugins around which should be capable of solving your issue, I don't have a specific one to recommend though.